# Scrollable div inside table cell using css

Tags: html, css

I want to be able to set a max width on the div and have the overflow be handled with scroll-bars.
This works in FF, but not in IE or chrome so well... the scrolling part seems to work OK but the width of the table doesn't adjust like it does in FF, the width is still accounting for the scrollable div in chrome and IE. FF the main table adjusts perfectly.
I realize that you're not supposed to use a `<div>` inside of a `<span>` etc, just want ideas on how to accomplish this overflow...

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gmcalab/JjZzV/10/)

Here is my example:

```
<div>     
    <table style="width: 100%">
        <tr>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>bar</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" class="uiTest">
                <span>
                    <div class="uiTableContainer">
                        <table class="uiTable" cellspacing="0">                                     <tbody>
                            <tr class="uiTableRow">
                                <td>
                                    foo
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    foo
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    foo
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    foo
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    foo
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    foo
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    foo
                                </td>
                                <td class="uiTableAction">
                                    foo
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    foo
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    foo
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    foo
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    foo
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    foo
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    foo
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    foo
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    foo
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    foo
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    foo
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    foo
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    foo
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    foo
                                </td>
                                <td class="uiTableAction">
                                    foo
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    foo
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    foo
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    foo
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    foo
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    foo
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    foo
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    foo
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    foo
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    foo
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    foo
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    foo
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    foo
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    foo
                                </td>
                                <td class="uiTableAction">
                                    foo
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    foo
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    foo
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    foo
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    foo
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    foo
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    foo
                                </td>
                                 <td>
                                    foo
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    foo
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    foo
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    foo
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    foo
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    foo
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    foo
                                </td>
                                <td class="uiTableAction">
                                    foo
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    foo
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    foo
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    foo
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    foo
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    foo
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    foo
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    foo
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    foo
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    foo
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    foo
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    foo
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    foo
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    foo
                                </td>
                                <td class="uiTableAction">
                                    foo
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    foo
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    foo
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    foo
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    foo
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    foo
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    foo
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    foo
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    foo
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    foo
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    foo
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    foo
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    foo
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    foo
                                </td>
                                <td class="uiTableAction">
                                    foo
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    foo
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    foo
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    foo
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    foo
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    foo
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    foo
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>bar</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

And the css:

```
.uiTable{
   border: 1px solid red;  
   width: 100%;
}

.uiTableContainer{

    max-width: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: I don't see what the problem is, the render identically in IE9, Chrome 16.0.891 dev and ff 6.0.2

Comment: No sir, they don't. The outer table stretchs the width of the inner table even though the inner has the scrollbar in IE7, IE8, & chrome 14.0.835, Thus creating the scroll bar for the inner table and the viewport itself.

Comment: Why are you putting a div in a span, exactly? If you want the `div` to act like a `span`, use CSS.

Comment: @Drackir, I specifically pointed out in my OP that I don't need commentary on that. Stick to the question at hand not the knit picking.

Comment: Call it nitpicking if you want, but if you're using the language in a way that's unintended and then getting unexpected results, well, IMO that's the first thing you should be looking at.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not the problem. I have already checked that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it necessary that you use "max-width" ?

I am getting good results in IE when using "width" instead.

Try: http://jsfiddle.net/NCB3a/

Tested in IE8 and FF6.0.2

Edit: Or to keep the max-width value, I guess this would also work:

```
max-width: 200px !important;
width:200px;
```